# XMLHttpRequest other page content missing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a widget Which displays average rating of company from my database.

Widget  will be displayed whereever javascript embed code is placed.

Here is my JS file:

link-widget.js

```
var company = document.getElementById("widget").getAttribute("data-name");
var rating;

function widget(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "link-widget.php?name="+company,true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { 
  if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) { 
   rating = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  document.write('<a href="https://www.example.com/company/'+company+'">Average Rating '+rating+'/5</a>');
  }
 };
 xmlhttp.send();
}

window.onload = widget;
```

and the embed code for displaying the widget is:

```
<script id="widget" data-name="company" src="https://www.example.com/manage/link-widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The Javascript is correctly getting the data from the database but the issue is its making the page blank and  only showing "Average rating .." on blank page and the page is repeatedly reloading. Other html content on the page is not showing up.

Please help. where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), you need to call `document.close()`:

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling document.open() will automatically call document.open. Once you have finished writing, it is recommended to call document.close() to tell the browser to finish loading the page.

However, you might also want to consider [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem!

```
var company = document.getElementById("widget").getAttribute("data-name");
var rating;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "link-widget.php?name="+company,true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { 
  if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) { 
   rating = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    display(this);
    }
 };
 xmlhttp.send();

 function display(json){

     document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML =
     '<a href="https://www.example.com/company/'+company+'">Average Rating '+rating+'/5</a>'; 
 }
```

and

```
<script id="widget" data-name="company" src="widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p id="avg"></p>
```